# A Sense of Event Binders in wxPython

Tags: wxpython

wxPython has a giant amount of event binders (for example, **wx.EVT_ACTIVATE**, **wx.EVT_ACTIVATE_APP**, **wx.EVT_COMMAND_ENTER**, **wx.EVT_COMMAND_FIND**, ...).

But I understand not always when I must use a concrete event binder.
For example, when do I have to use the event binder **wx.EVT_ACTIVATE_APP**?

Please, help me to understand.

Why PyQt does not have the event binders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out what the events are in the documentation. See the following link for EVT_ACTIVATE_APP.

[An activate event is sent when a window or application is being activated or deactivated.](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ActivateEvent.html?highlight=evt_activate_app)

PyQt uses singals and slots for event binding.